# How can I improve the speed of my simple neural network?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, tf.keras

I've just started exploring TensorFlow and I'm facing an issue regarding performance. As a starting example, I tried implementing a model to simulate a logic gate. Let's say there are two inputs `A` and `B` and one output `Y`. Suppose `Y` depended only on `B` and not on `A`. That means that the following are valid examples:

```
[0, 0] -> 0
[1, 0] -> 0
[0, 1] -> 1
[1, 1] -> 1
```

I created training sets for this data and created a model that uses a `DenseFeatures` layer using two features `A` and `B`. This layer feeds into a `Dense(128, 'relu')` layer, which feeds into a `Dense(16, 'relu')` layer, which finally feeds into a `Dense(1, 'sigmoid')` layer.

Training this NN works fine and the predictions are perfect. However, I noticed that on my MacBook, each prediction takes about 250ms. This is too much, since my final goal is to use such a NN to test hundreds of predictions each second.

So I stripped the network down to `DenseFeatures([A, B]) -> Dense(8, 'relu') -> Dense(1, 'sigmoid')`, however predictions for this NN still takes the same about of time. I was expecting that the execution speed depends on the complexity of the model. I can see that this is not the case here? What am I doing wrong?

Also, I had read that TensorFlow uses floating point math for accuracy but this has a penalty hit in terms of performance and if we convert our data to use integer math, it would speed things up. However, I have no idea of how to achieve that.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me understand why predictions for such a simple logic gate and such a simple NN is taking this long. And how can I speed it up.

For reference, here is my code in python:

```
  import random
  from typing import Any, List

  import numpy as np
  import tensorflow as tf
  from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
  from tensorflow import feature_column
  from tensorflow.keras import layers

  class Input:
    def __init__(self, data: List[int]):
      self.data = data

  class Output:
    def __init__(self, value: float):
      self.value = value

  class Item:
    def __init__(self, input: Input, output: Output):
      self.input = input
      self.output = output

  DATA: List[Item] = []
  for i in range(10000):
    x = Input([random.randint(0, 1), random.randint(0, 1)])
    y = Output(x.data[1])
    DATA.append(Item(x, y))

  BATCH_SIZE = 5
  DATA_TRAIN, DATA_TEST = train_test_split(DATA,       shuffle=True, test_size=0.2)
  DATA_TRAIN, DATA_VAL  = train_test_split(DATA_TRAIN, shuffle=True, test_size=0.2/0.8)

  def toDataSet(data: List[Item], shuffle: bool, batch_size: int):
    a = {
      'a': [x.input.data[0] for x in data],
      'b': [x.input.data[1] for x in data],
    }
    b = [x.output.value for x in data]
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((a, b)).shuffle(buffer_size=len(data)).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

  DS_TRAIN = toDataSet(DATA_TRAIN, True, 5)
  DS_VAL   = toDataSet(DATA_VAL, True, 5)
  DS_TEST  = toDataSet(DATA_TEST, True, 5)

  FEATURES = []
  FEATURES.append(a)
  FEATURES.append(b)
  feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(FEATURES)
  model = tf.keras.models.load_model('MODEL.H5')
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    feature_layer,
    layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
  ])
  model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
  model.fit(DS_TRAIN, validation_data=DS_VAL, epochs=10)
  loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(DS_TEST)

  for i in range(1000):
    val = model.predict([np.array([random.randint(0, 1)]), np.array([random.randint(0, 1)])])
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are only using integers, change the input of the model to use 8-bit signed integers. You can do this by changing the datatype in your input layer by adding the *dtype* parameter. This will vastly improve processing speed since you won't be wasting calculations.

Comment: Hi! I tried looking into it but I couldn't figure out what value to set `dtype` to. I know I can set it to `'float32'` and `'float64'` but I was unable to find what string represents 8-bit signed integers. Also, could you explain if I would need to scale my inputs and labels to account for this?

Comment: 8 bit signed integers are ‘int8’. You can also get a list of all available data types if you Google “Tensorflow data types”. Let me know how it works out.